# Operations betzeen matrix and scalar in breeze

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

Adendo: This seems to be a scala IDE bug because everythong compiles and run smoothly by using the command line sbt. I'd close the question, but StackOverflow won't allow

I am unable to sum or multiply a matrix by a scalar in Breeze
If I try:

```
val z = DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](5,3)
z + 2.0
```

I get two errors:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter op: breeze.linalg.operators.OpAdd.Impl2[breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double],Double,That]
not enough arguments for method +: (implicit op: breeze.linalg.operators.OpAdd.Impl2[breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double],Double,That])That. Unspecified value parameter op.
```

The same thing happens if I try * , :* , *: , :+ and +: with slightly different errors.
Things work if it is a DenseVector and not a DenseMatrix  and I use :+ .
If I try it in scala IDE worksheet, it produces the error but correctly prints the resulting matrix.
I'm using Scala IDE 4.4.1 , breeze 0.12 , scala 2.11.8

Comment: Hmm, works for me. What does your import statement look like? Are you using the `2.11` version of breeze?

Comment: I'm using import breeze.linalg._  in order to import and breeze 0.12. However your comment made me try to compile bypassing eclipse and it seems that it is a bug (I edited my question) , so the question is pointless

Comment: It is more likely that it is a configuration error rather than a Scala IDE bug. I would check your `build.sbt` file and make sure your project is setup properly.

Comment: Same problem. Scala 2.12. Works on SBT, won't work on Scala IDE. I don't know if is a configuration problem or a bug, but is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If someone faces this problem. The solution is quite simple.

Step 1
Close the project or Scala IDE

Step 2
From SBT execute, clean and later on eclipse command.

Step 3
Open eclipse again.

Eclipse should resolve the implicit conversions.